# Flycheck gives errors, when I use shellcheck as linter for bash scripts

Tags: flycheck, bash

I use GNU Emacs 26.0.50 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.18.9) of 2017-06-09, and Shellcheck 0.3.7 als linter for bash scripts (https://www.shellcheck.net).

When I open a bash script, I get errors from Flycheck, which makes it
unusable for me. Verbatim from message buffer:

> Try installing a more recent version of sh-shellcheck, and please open
>   a bug report if the issue persists in the latest release.  Thanks!
>   Suspicious state from syntax checker sh-shellcheck: Flycheck checker
>   sh-shellcheck returned non-zero exit code 3, but its output contained
>   no errors: unrecognized option `--external-sources'
>
> Usage: shellcheck [OPTIONS...] FILES...   -e CODE1,CODE2.. 
>   --exclude=CODE1,CODE2..  exclude types of warnings   -f FORMAT         --format=FORMAT          output format   -s SHELLNAME      --shell=SHELLNAME        Specify dialect (bash,sh,ksh)   -V                --version                Print version information

It seems nobody is experiencing the same issue. I tested it with bare Emacs, and standard Shellcheck. How could I debug this further?

Answer (score 5):

apt installs an old version of flycheck,
https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/issues/704
that does not support --external-sources, this particular commit has been merged at flycheck recently
https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/pull/1256/files/7b35a1b17e415ecc8f9fc04b3a043a3afb40599c and make use of such feature.
The solution is simple, just opt-out of it. Just like suggested [here](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/pull/1256)

```
  (setq flycheck-shellcheck-follow-sources nil)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, CESCO. However, it disables Flycheck for bash scripts I suppose?

Comment: No it does not. I just disables this specific feature